# CSS pseudo selectors with Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

I have seen in a lot of the Material UI code that they use pseudo selectors in their react styled components. I thought I would try to do it myself and I cannot get it to work. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong or if this is even possible.

I am trying to make some CSS that will offset this element against the fixed header.

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStyles, WithStyles, withStyles, Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
import { TypographyProps } from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import GithubSlugger from 'github-slugger';
import Link from './link';

const styles = () =>
  createStyles({
    h: {
      '&::before': {
        content: 'some content',
        display: 'block',
        height: 60,
        marginTop: -60
      }
    }
  });

interface Props extends WithStyles<typeof styles>, TypographyProps {
  children: string;
}

const AutolinkHeader = ({ classes, children, variant }: Props) => {
  // I have to call new slugger here otherwise on a re-render it will append a 1
  const slug = new GithubSlugger().slug(children);

  return (
    <Link to={`#${slug}`}>
      <Typography classes={{ root: classes.h }} id={slug} variant={variant} children={children} />
    </Link>
  );
};

export default withStyles(styles)(AutolinkHeader);
```

Answer (score 243, accepted):

I found out that the content attribute needed to be double quoted like this

```
const styles = () =>
  createStyles({
    h: {
      '&::before': {
        content: '"some content"',
        display: 'block',
        height: 60,
        marginTop: -60
      }
    }
  });
```

and then everything worked like expected

Comment: content: ' "some content" ',
you missed the closed quote but anyway thanks, you saved my day.

Comment: This is also important for empty pseudo-elements. i.e. `content: '""'`

Comment: wasted 2 hours on that. I was using content: 'blabla' and it was not working ‍♂️

Comment: Well, content wasted my time.

Comment: Also wasted a few hours on this. My situation was even shittier as eslint is quite strict on this project I am working on and we're not allowing single quotes. For those in the same boat, just add this line before the `content` property: `/* eslint quotes: [2, "double", "avoid-escape"]  */` as this would allow strings to use single or double quotes as long as the string contains a quote that would have to be escaped otherwise.

Answer (score 53):

As @Eran Goldin said, check the value of your `content` property and make sure it's set to a string `""`. Odds are, you are doing something like this:

```js
'&::before': {
  content: '',
  ...
}
```

Which doesn't set the `content` property at all in the output stylesheet

```css
.makeStyles-content-154:before {
  content: ;
  ...
}
```

In Material-UI style object, the content of the string is the css value, *including* the double quote, to fix it simply write

```js
'&::before': {
  content: '""', // "''" will also work.
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Without having to explicitly set a height**

The above solutions require explicit height. If you want height to be dynamic, you can do something like this:

```
  &::after {
    content: '_'; // Any character can go here
    visibility: hidden;
  }
```