# Cannot create a toggle switch with React JSS (react-jss)

Tags: reactjs, jss

I'm trying to create a toggle switch by following this [example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_switch) in my React project. I'm using react-jss to help with the styling. I ran into an issue where the content style property with empty '' is not rendered on the page. This essentially creates the circle for the switch. I'm not sure what needs to be done here.

The style in question

```
.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}
```

In the stylesheet I'm setting it up like so

```
  slider : {
    '&:before' : {
        position: 'absolute',
        content: '',
        height: '26px',
        width: '26px',
        top: '4px',
        left: '4px',
        bottom: '4px',
        borderRadius : '50%',
        backgroundColor : 'white',
        '-webkit-transition': '0.4s',
        transition: '0.4s'
    }
 }
```

Comment: I think this style not complete, you must add these in slider too:   position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;

and your issue will resolve...

Comment: See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53768260/css-pseudo-selectors-with-material-ui) which is concerning material-ui but uses JSS under the hood. You need to double quote your `content` property like: `content: "''"`.

Comment: Good point from lawrence-witt  too

Comment: @lawrence-witt Thanks! The double quotes helped.